# Decide whether to display v-list-group based on permissions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I created a v-list-group, but when I judge the permissions to hide the v-list-group, the icon is still displayed, how can I hide the icon?

This is my display on the manager page

[image]

This is what I display on the user page

[image]

This is part of my code

```
        <v-list-group :value="false" no-action>
          <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon style="color:white">mdi-account-lock</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title style="color:white">{{
              fixed.title
            }}</v-list-item-title>
          </template>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="admin in admins"
            :key="admin.text"
            link
            router
            :to="admin.route">
            <v-list-item-title style="color:white">{{
              admin.text
            }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>
```

```
    showadminPage() {
      var role = localStorage.getItem("roles");
      this.admins = [];
      if (role === "admin") {
        this.admins.push(
          {text: "aaa",route: "/Healths"},
          {text: "bbb",route: "/CLearning"},
          {text: "ccc",route: "/Schedule"},
          {text: "ddd",route: "/Competence"},
          {text: "eee",route: "/QzNumber"});}},
```

Comment: how are you hiding the v-list-group. it is not clear in your code.

Comment: @IgorMoraru You can watch showadminPage(), if the role is not admin, I will not go up the data

Comment: i get it. so the problem is that you are passing an empty list to v-list-group if not admin, so the component is present but with no items to show. the activator icon is present to show or to hide the list items, regardless of wether there are any items to show or not. if you want to hide the activator icon you have the option to hide the entire v-list-group component, for ex. with v-if or v-show, to render a v-list-item instead of v-list-group, or to bind a class to the component and set the display option in css.

Comment: @IgorMoraru Thank you !! I know where the code mistake is

Comment: @YI-YI How did you solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks